# VB: Email sending with SMTP is failing

Tags: vb.net, windows, email, smtp, desktop-application

I'm adding an email sender in my app, so i used this:

```
Try
    Dim oMail As New SmtpMail("TryIt")
    Dim oSmtp As New SmtpClient()
    oMail.From = "app-NHK@hotmail.com" ' From
    oMail.To = "NHKomaiha@hotmail.com" ' To
    oMail.Subject = Title.Text 'Title
    oMail.TextBody = MsgTxt.Text 'Body
    Dim oServer As New SmtpServer("smtp.live.com") ' SMTP server address
    oServer.User = "app-NHK@hotmail.com" 'here i have written my app's email address made for sending the email from this form
    oServer.Password = "thepassword" 'here i have put my app email password
    oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto ' if SSL connection required
    UseWaitCursor = True
```

Here done setting the main needed info

```
    oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail)
```

Sending...

```
    UseWaitCursor = False
    MessageBox.Show("E-Mail Sent Successfully", "Contact by E-Mail", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    Main.BringToFront()
    Main.Enabled = True
    Close()
```

Error catching...

```
Catch ep As Exception
    UseWaitCursor = False
    MessageBox.Show("Error while sending E-Mail." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ep.Message, "Contact by E-Mail", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Dim closeerror = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to close?", "Contact by E-Mail", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If closeerror = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Main.BringToFront()
        Main.Enabled = True
        Close()
    End If
End Try
```

Is this code wrong? i used a lot of ways to send email but none worked

This time i got error: `550 5.3.4 Requested action not taken; To continue sending messages, please sign in to your account.`

Comment: see if [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20546/How-to-Send-Mails-from-your-GMAIL-Account-through) helps

Comment: @PauloLima error: `mailbox unavailable`..etc...

Answer (score 2):

Modify and try this working example:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
...
Try
    Dim Email As New MailMessage()
    Email.From = New MailAddress("abcdef@gmail.com")
    Email.To.Add("other@provider.com")
    Email.Subject = "Subject"
    Email.IsBodyHtml = False        'or true if you want html
    Email.Body = TextBox1.Text

    Dim EmailClient As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    EmailClient.EnableSsl = True
    EmailClient.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("abcdef@gmail.com", "password")
    EmailClient.Timeout = 7000
    EmailClient.Send(Email)

Catch ex As SmtpException
    MsgBox(ex.StatusCode & vbCrLf & ex.Message, vbCritical, "SMTP Error!")
End Try
```

Comment: code is right but error: 550 mailbox is unabvailable

Comment: And got the same text of the above `ex.Message` (`5.3.4 requested action...etc..`)

Comment: Code was tested with many servers and works properly. I think that problem is with configuraton. See: https://together.jolla.com/question/59505/solvedhow-to-setup-outgoing-smtp-server-for-hotmail-on-jolla/

Comment: I've not got a solution from this link, I'm not finding any wrong thing in my configuration i tried changing to `smtp-mail.outlook.com` and changing port, but now the error is `timed out`

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to specify port and authentication type in order to connect to an smtp server. It seems that `smtp.live.com` use `SSL` and port `465` (please verify this data).

So you can use [SmtpClient.Port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.port%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to sets the port used for SMTP transactions and [SmtpClient.EnableSSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify that `SmtpClient` uses Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) to encrypt the connection.

Comment: I have the SSL connection but probably I've inserted a wrong port number, ill test this

Comment: EDIT: i got error: `-1 Failure sending message.` my full code: http://dpaste.com/142HBFJ

Comment: Hmmmm... In example Gmail help say port 465+SSL, but works on port 587+SSL... 465 returns timeout.

Comment: So what's the problem of my code? (http://dpaste.com/142HBFJ) i'm not finding a mistake